# remote control of vlc using script over ssh

Tags: shell-script, remote

I'm trying to control vlc video playback on a remote machine using a script and remote ssh. I have machine A, which logs into machine B with this command:

```
# sshpass -p <password> ssh user@<machine-B-ip> screen -d -m ./playvideo.sh
```

machine B contains playvideo.sh and starts the vlc playback, it works but I then need to stop it after a certain number of seconds by command from machine A but can't work out how to do this. I know I need to reconnect and log back into the screen previously created, issue a 'stop' command and then exit but 'screen -r' doesn't work, screen -r gives an error:

```
# sshpass -p <password> ssh user@<machine-B-ip> screen -r echo stop
'Must be connected to a terminal.'
```

how do I get back into the screen on machine B and issue the word 'stop' in the terminal?

Comment: Please post your Script  Instead of forcing screen to stop, would it not be easier to pass arguments to `playvideo.sh` such as `--play`, `--stop`, `--pause`, `--rewind`, and `--fast-forward` with maybe an `--exit`?

Comment: maybe use '-t' ? ```ssh user@host -t screen``` ?